# Conflict library in maven

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a project created with Jhipste 3.4.2. Adding the library JasperReport 6.2.2.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The project fails to boot. And I see it's a problem with the library lucene-core. Elasticsearch uses 4.10.4 and JasperReport 4.5.1
As you can solve this problem.

Use

sprint-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

sprint-boot-starter-parent (1.3.5.RELEASE)

[image]

Comment: Which of the two versions of JasperReport is finally on the classpath?

Comment: It seems that your classpath uses the OLDER version of lucene-core (sorry about saying JasperReport first). I would try to define the new version 4.10.4 in the DependencyManagement section of your project.

Comment: exclude the older version from jasperreports and try again

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. As I can not include the previous version of lucene-core JasperReport. Can you tell me how to do it and where.
Thanks for your colaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer is, add the following code to POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the dependency entry for jasperreports:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

So `lucene-core` 4.5.1 will not be drawn by jasperreports, and you can specify the version that you want to use.

By now, the version 4.5.1 is used because in the dependency hierarchy it is nearer to your own pom than version 4.10.4:

This is the long path to 4.10.4: `sprint-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch --> spring-data-elasticsearch --> elasticsearch --> lucene-core`

This is the short path to 4.5.1: `jasperreports --> lucene-core`

Comment: I also added dependencies Lucene.

Comment: @joseluisgarciacespedes and what was the result?